# When i run this npm i coomand in console, i'm getting following errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend, mern

C:\Users\INTAG\Desktop\Topics in Cs\MERN project> npm i axios react-alert react-alert-template-basic react-helmet react-redux redux redux-thunk redux-devtools-extension react-router-dom overlay-navbar
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ecommerce@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.1 || ^17" from react-alert@7.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-alert
npm ERR!     react-alert@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^16.8.1 || ^17" from react-alert@7.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-alert
npm ERR!       react-alert@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (react-alert-template-basic, react-helmet)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! react-redux@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.72.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     peerOptional react-native@">=0.59" from react-redux@8.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!       react-redux@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\INTAG\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-24T21_38_26_752Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\INTAG\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-24T21_38_26_752Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\INTAG\Desktop\Topics in Cs\MERN project>